# cant send mail.?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have create a function which to send mail. Its works when I invoke in main(). But when I invoke it from jsp, or from other class its throw exception
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException"

Comment: If you could post your code, that would be extremely helpful.  However, my guess is that you don't have the javamail library referenced in your jsp application's classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems javaxmail jar is not presnet in WEB-INF/lib folder in your webapp. Jar containing javax.mail.* is required for web application to send mail if using default java package.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include JavaMail on the classpath of your web application.

Comment: yea thanks. I have'nt place mail.jar and activator.jar in tomcat lib.